# Android Studio is not detecting Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-8.1, nexus-7

I am using `Android Studio 1.1.0` under `Windows 8.1 Pro` and trying to connect my `Nexus 7` running `Android version 5.1`.

I am following both [Lynda tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/Android-Studio-tutorials/Connecting-physical-devices-testing/361465/373371-4.html) and looking at [android developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) tutorials but was not able to find what's wrong.

The device is visible in the `Device Manager`:

[image]

The `Google USB driver` has been installed:

[image]

I have enabled a lot of `Developer options` of my `Nexus 7` including:

- USB debugging
- Stay awake
- Bug report shortcut

I am not seeing the details when I try either to `run` or `debug` the application. The device is not listed here (as shown in the video):

[image]

I have try to:

- add `android:debuggable="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`
- restart the PC
- reconnect the device

I was not able to find `Unknown sources` option in the `Developer options` which was recommended in some other answers of this issue.

Could you advice what to try?

---

[image]

Comment: Disabling and re-enabling USB debugging solves my problem 98% of the time, have you tried that?

Comment: @IntegralOfTan Thanks, I've try it (enable/disable it several times) but still nothing.

Comment: Can you manually detect it with ADB?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Sorry, could you give me a link or more details of what you want me to check?

Comment: @gotqn ADB - Android Debug Bridge. Adb is located in your Android SDK folder. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: @JaredBurrows Check the edit of the question. Did you want me to do this?

Comment: Click in the device manager listing to see the USB VID & PID which may have changed.  On Windows you could be stuck having to use a universal driver or edit inf files; on OSX and to a degree Linux this is much simpler.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is getting too complex for beginner like me. I even don't know why I have started to install the android stuff on windows. I have dual boot (`Windows 8.1` and `Ubuntu`), so I am going to give a try to the Linux.

Comment: On linux, you need to follow the instructions for udev rules, and make sure you have one for the USB VID & PID which you can get with 'lsusb' - and that if you use their current proposal for the rule, you change the default owner username to yours.

Comment: @gotqn Yes. Using ADB is what Android Studio is going to use to connect to your phone. Can you run `adb devices`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to change my `OS` and install `Ubuntu 15.04` instead. After I installed the `Android Studio` what I needed to do was to simply connect my `Nexus 7` with my computer - the studio detected it immediately - no additional drivers and settings were needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Click Revoke USB debugging authorization in Developer option and try it again.

Go to Settings -> Usb Connectivity -> Usb connection mode -> Check MTP mode.

And try sudo adb devices.

Comment: Nothing changed. Оn the devices I am getting `No Connected Devices`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest re-installing your ADB Drive in the Android SDK file and making sure your device is in Debugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer settings and change USB-mode to Charging.
Solution for Android M.